# Is there a way to update a child in Firebase without triggering observe function?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, when user unfollows another user I want the corresponding follow notification to be deleted from firebase. But when I'm updating the reference of that notification the observe function gets triggered immediately and the new notification gets deleted.

So how can i -if there is a way- update notification value without triggering observer function?

Below are my functions of uploading notifications and deleting them "Follow notifications"

```
func uploadNotification(toUser user: User, type: NotificationType, postID: String? = nil){
      guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
      //users do not get notifications of themselevs
      guard uid != user.uid else { return }
      var values: [String: Any] = ["timestamp": Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970),
                                   "uid": uid,
                                   "type": type.rawValue]
      
      if let postID = postID {
          values["postID"] = postID
      }
      REF_NOTIFICATIONS.child(user.uid).childByAutoId().updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
          
          guard let reference = ref.key else { return }
          
          if type == .follow {
              REF_FOLLOW_NOTIFICATIONS.child(user.uid).updateChildValues([reference: String(type.rawValue)])
          }
      }
  }

func unfollowUser(uid: String, completion: @escaping DatabaseCompletion) {
      guard let currentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
       self.deleteFollowNotification(uid: uid)
      
      
      REF_USER_FOLLOWING.child(currentUID).child(uid).removeValue { (error, ref) in
          REF_USER_FOLLOWERS.child(uid).child(currentUID).removeValue(completionBlock: completion)
         
      }
  }
  
  
  func deleteFollowNotification(uid: String){
      REF_FOLLOW_NOTIFICATIONS.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
          
           let notificationKey = snapshot.key
          REF_NOTIFICATIONS.child(uid).child(notificationKey).removeValue()
          
      }
      REF_FOLLOW_NOTIFICATIONS.child(uid).removeValue()
      
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to make a database observer completely ignore a specific update.  You will either have to remove the observer entirely, or write some code in it that decides if it should take action when it's been invoked.